# React Native fetch replays cached request after switching WIFI

Tags: android, react-native, fetch, wifi, android-wifi

We're building an app for switching to and authenticating with a specific WIFI network. We're using the fetch API and have also implemented some cache-disabling mechanisms (like the Headers for Cache-Control, Cache, Pragma, Expires, etc.) and are also appending a random number via query parameter to every request to stop requests from not actually beeing sent to the server. It all works fine up onto the point where, when the user switches between networks and the tries to authenticate via the app, the request is executed as if the user is still connected with the previous WIFI, altough even netinfo shows, he isn't anymore.

To illustrate, the two error cases step-by-step:

1. User is in correct WIFI and authenticates successfully within the app (only works if in this WIFI)
2. User switches to different WIFI and tries to authenticate within the app and it works -> this should not work, but the response from the fetch request is the same as if connected to the appropriate WIFI

Second error case (basically the other way around):

1. User is in wrong WIFI and tries to authenticate within the app (doesn't and shouldn't work, all is fine)
2. User switches to correct WIFI and tries to authenticate, which should work now, but it doesn't because in the logs in the debug app I see that the response to the request is the same as if the device would still be connected to the wrong WIFI network

When restarting the app after changing the WIFI network, all works as expected, but this cannot be the solution, at least not from a UX perspective.

Also, the problem even occurs if just switching between mobile data on and off (because authentication only works if mobile data is off). Even then the requests are cached if they are tried in the "wrong" network.

Funny enough, the problem seems to only be occuring on Android, iOS is not affected.

This problem is completely freezing development currently, so any help is very much appreciated!